# Android Fragment Example - startActivity silently failing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working through this example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Example

In landscape orientation this works as intended, but I'm running into a problem in portrait. Upon selecting an item from the shown ListFragment nothing happens. The logs indicate the ActivityManager is reacting correctly to the intent however I'm seeing nothing on the screen save a selected ListView.

At first I thought this was a manifest issue, but it behaves the same even with the respective activity tag.

Anyone know what might be the problem? If it matters, I'm currently testing this on a 3.1 device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've moved stuff around, edited the title to reflect the exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by moving the inner class to another file. For whatever reason, and in spite of the class being referenced correctly, the activity failed to display. I'm not certain of exactly why this is, but I feel a more common pattern is putting different activities in different files anyway.